# angular 2 with webpack on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I have created a sample application using dotnet core, I have also implemented web-pack for bundling angular.

My problem is the bundled file is really big, around 6MB.

Here is my `polyfills.ts` file

```
import 'ie-shim'; // Internet Explorer 9 support.

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-set';
import 'core-js/es6/typed';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect'; 
import 'ts-helpers';
```

Here my is network status

[image]

1. How can I reduce the file size of the bundled file?
2. `<my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>` This text is showing before the component is visible, how can I speed up it?

Comment: Are you sure that that's a release build? I've noticed that the change in size when using the `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` is pretty huge. Webpack in develop mode is very verbose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the webpack, you need to use the command parameter p for production.

```
webpack -p --progress
```